# Nested routes in React Router v4 not rendering as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I've spent the last few days trying to get my nested routes to work, and I have to say that I'm completely lost.

I'm trying to get the following functionality to work:

1. Sidebar with several links. One of them leads to /banking.
2. /banking by default renders component `{ BankingCards }` inside a `{ CardWrapper }`.
3. When user clicks on the `<Link>` of one of the 4 cards rendered by `{ BankingCards }`, I want to render the nested path inside of the same `{ CardWrapper }`.

In the code block below, you will notice I tried using a switch statement to dynamically assign a component to `actionComponent`. This seems to break the functionality in more ways than one.

Is it the approach that is wrong, or am I missing something about React Router components?

```
// Banking.js

import CardWrapper from '../../Wrappers/CardWrapper/CardWrapper';
import BankingCards from './BankingCards/BankingCards';
import AddBank from './AddBank/AddBank';
import AddDebit from './AddDebit/AddDebit';
import AddCredit from './AddCredit/AddCredit';
import AddDirect from './AddDirect/AddDirect';

class Banking extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log(match.params);
    // let actionComponent;
    // switch (match.params.actionType) { 
    //   case 'add-bank':
    //   actionComponent = AddBank;
    //     break;
    //   case 'add-debit':
    //   actionComponent = AddDebit;
    //     break;
    //   case 'add-credit':
    //   actionComponent = AddCredit;
    //     break;
    //   case 'add-direct':
    //   actionComponent = AddDirect;
    //     break;
    //   default:
    //     return null;
    // }
    return (
      <div className={classes.Banking}>
        <h1 className={classes.mainHeader}>Banking</h1>
        <CardWrapper>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={BankingCards} />
            <Route path={`${match.path}/:actionType`} component={actionComponent} /> 
          </Switch>
        </CardWrapper>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and

```
// BankingCards.js

const bankingCards = ({ match }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <h1>Add Bank Account</h1>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/add-bank`}>
          <SVG src={iconPlus} className={classes.iconPlus} />
        </Link>
        <h3>Manage accounts</h3>
      </Card>

      <Card>
        <h1>Add Debit Card</h1>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/add-debit`}>
          <SVG src={iconPlus} className={classes.iconPlus} />
        </Link>
        <h3>Manage debit cards</h3>
      </Card>

      <Card>
        <h1>Add Credit Card</h1>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/add-credit`}>
          <SVG src={iconPlus} className={classes.iconPlus} />
        </Link>
        <h3>Manage credit cards</h3>
      </Card>

      <Card>
        <h1>Add Direct Debit</h1>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/add-direct`}>
          <SVG src={iconPlus} className={classes.iconPlus} />
        </Link>
        <h3>Manage direct debits</h3>
      </Card>
    </>
  ); 
};
```

Comment: what does print `console.log(match.params);` ?

Comment: An empty object. That was when I realised I wasn't doing something right.

Comment: one solution could be to use the `render` prop instead of `component`, you can do your switch case inside it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Found a solution after digging deeper on the website

There were 3 issues with my code:

1. I should have used `render` prop instead of `component` for the dynamic `Route`.

   ```
   <Switch>
     <Route path={`${match.path}/:actionType`} render={props => {
       const actionType = props.match.params.actionType;
       const Component = getActionComponent(actionType);
       if (Component) {
         return <Component {...props} />;
       } else {
         return <Redirect to="/" />
       }
     }} /> 
     <Route path={`${match.path}`} component={BankingCards} />
   </Switch>
   ```
2. Also, the dynamic route should have come before the `/banking` one. This is because the `Switch` statement will only render the first match. `/banking` was already a partial match, so the router wasn't reaching the nested routes like `/banking/add-bank`.
3. The parent route, `/banking`, had the `exact` prop set to `true`. I now know that when using nested routes the parent route should not have `exact` enabled.

   ```
   class MainArea extends Component {
     state = {};

     render() {
       return (
         <div className={classes.MainArea}>
           <Route path="/banking" component={Banking} />
           <Route exact path="/planner" component={Planner} />
           <Route exact path="/notes" component={Notes} />
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [render function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) to fix your example. You have an error because in the `Banking` component `math.params` doens't have the `actionType` propertye.

```
function getActionComponent(actionType) {
   switch (actionType) { 
     case 'add-bank':
       return AddBank;
     case 'add-debit':
       return AddDebit;
     case 'add-credit':
         return AddCredit;
     case 'add-direct':
        return AddDirect;
     default:
        return null;
}

<Route path={`${match.path}/:actionType`} render={props => {
    const actionType = props.match.params.actionType;
    const Component = getActionComponent(actionType);
    if (Component) {
       return <Component {...props}/>;
    } else {
       return <Redirect to="/"/>
    }
}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Olivier. I gave it a go, but it still doesn't work. I console logged the `actionType` and `Component` inside of the render, and still nothing comes up. And just like before, I can see that it's taking me to /banking/add-bank in the url, but the `<Banking />` component isn't rendering at all. As in, not even the `<h1>Banking</h1>` heading is displaying. I would at least expect it to render that, but not the `<CardWrapper />`.

Comment: if `Banking` is not showing, the problem is related to the route responsible to display the `Banking` component, can you show us the code ?

Comment: You were right with both suggestions. I have now posted an update.